# How to customize the default CREATE_USER functionality in django auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using django-social-auth for facebook login which creates a new user if it doesn't exist in the db, else updates the existing db entry. I think it checks for `fb_username` OR `fb_uid` in the database to check if the user exists or not.

**Requirements:**
In my application, i need to be able to create a user by manually inserting his info in db. And this row should be updated when the user logs_in with facebook.

So I manually created an entry with all the information of the user i.e. `fb_username, fb_uid, email, first_name, last_name, hometown... etc.`
But what happens when the user logs_in is, a new entry is created instead of updating the manually created entry. So i really don't understand what fields does it use to check if the user exists or not. What would be the best way to go from here?

**Extra Info:** I am extending the user model of django to `UserProfile` using a one-to-one relationship and `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'`

Comment: how its creates new entry when user logs in ?

Comment: i am using the django-social-auth library... after configuring the library with required fields, it takes care of creating or updating the entry. To update the extra (UserProfile) information as soon as the user is created, i use a custom [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it was editing this default pipeline

`'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',`

by changing the

`def create_user(backend,details,response,username,user=None,*args,**kwargs):
    if user: 
        return {'user': user}
    if not username:
        return None`

to

`def create_user(backend,details,response,username,user=None,*args,**kwargs):
    username = User.objects.get(u_name=username)
    if username:
        return {'user': username}
    if not username:
        return None`